# Erro ao pegar um elemento json com php

Tags: php, json

**Eu tenho o seguinte resultado em json:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [LocalObservationDateTime] => 2019-11-12T19:20:00-03:00
            [EpochTime] => 1573597200
            [WeatherText] => Algumas nuvens
            [WeatherIcon] => 36
            [HasPrecipitation] => 
            [PrecipitationType] => 
            [IsDayTime] => 
            [Temperature] => Array
                (
                    [Metric] => Array
                        (
                            [Value] => 28.7
                            [Unit] => C
                            [UnitType] => 17
                        )

                    [Imperial] => Array
                        (
                            [Value] => 84
                            [Unit] => F
                            [UnitType] => 18
                        )

                )

            [RealFeelTemperature] => Array
                (
                    [Metric] => Array
                        (
                            [Value] => 32.7
                            [Unit] => C
                            [UnitType] => 17
                        )

                    [Imperial] => Array
                        (
                            [Value] => 91
                            [Unit] => F
                            [UnitType] => 18
                        )   
                )
[...]
```

**Eu estou tentando pegar com PHP desta forma:**

```
<?php
$detalhes = $data["WeatherText"];
//também tentei desta forma abaixo:
$detalhes = $data->WeatherText;
?>
```

Faço um `var_dump($detalhes)`, retorna `NULL`

Onde eu estou errando?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Está dando problema porque seu objeto é um `array` cujo o primeiro elemento é um `array`.

Um exemplo com um objeto de estrutura similar ao seu:

```
<?php

//Aqui o JSON é um array cujo o dois elementos são objetos
$json = '[ {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}, {"f":10,"g":20,"h":30,"i":40,"j":50} ]';

//Converte o JSON em array associativo
$arr = json_decode($json, true);

//Imprime a estrutura do array associativo
print_r($arr);

//Imprime o valor da chave 'c' do primeiro elemento
print($arr[0]["c"]);

?>
```

Ao fazer `print_r($arr);` o resultado é estrutura do JSON como um array associativo:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [a] => 1
            [b] => 2
            [c] => 3
            [d] => 4
            [e] => 5
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [f] => 10
            [g] => 20
            [h] => 30
            [i] => 40
            [j] => 50
        )

)
```

E ao fazer `print($arr[0]["c"]);` o resultado é :

```
3
```

Então voltando ao seu exemplo para obter o valor desejado referencie o elemento que quer acessar seguido da chave cujo quer obter o valor:

```
$detalhes = $data[0]["WeatherText"];
```

Link do código no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/SoreElderlyDefinition)

Comment: Obrigado pela a resposta. No momento a API que estou utilizando excedeu o limite de solicitação diária. Amanhã irei tentar novamente e volto aqui com o resultado.

Comment: @Léo, Ok, estou aguardando o resultado.

Comment: deu certo, grato!